# How to serialize DataTable present as a class's Member using protoBuffer

Tags: c#, serialization, datatable, protobuf-net

I am trying to serialized a class using protobuf-net. The class contains Datatable member. I can successfully serialize and deserialize that class without DataTable but with DataTable, it shows Exception: No serializer defined for DataTable.
However, I tried to serialize DataTable separately using ProtoBuf.Data and it works!
But I want something that can serialize entire class including DataTable using protobuf-net. 
MyCodes:

```
     public enum Name { SS,RR};


     [ProtoContract(SkipConstructor = true)]
     class StaticField 
    {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public static int o  = 0;
    [ProtoMember(7)]
    public IA Aa;
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    private readonly int s = 12;
    [ProtoMember(3)]

    public Name name { get; set; }

    public DataTable dataTable { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public Dictionary<int, string> GetNames = new Dictionary<int, string>();
    public StaticField()
    {
        FillUpDict();
        dataTable = GetTable();
    }
```

My Codes for Serializing StaticField Class:

```
         StaticField.No = 2;
        StaticField staticField
            = new StaticField();
        staticField.Aa = new A();
        staticField.name = Name.RR;
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, staticField);            
            array = stream.ToArray();
        }
```

My Codes for serializing DataTable separately:

```
      using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (IDataReader reader = staticField.dataTable.CreateDataReader())
        {
            DataSerializer.Serialize(stream, reader);
            array2 = stream.ToArray();
        }
```